# is this overkill, or the wrong strategy (cross validation for random forest regression)

Tags: cross-validation, python, random-forest, scikit-learn

trying to find the best random forest, here's a snippet of pseudocode (i've already pulled out a validation set from X

```
i= 10
while i < 250: #250 ~ sqrt(len(x_train))
    X_train, X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
    m_ske = ske.RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators= i)
    m_multi = skl_multi.MultiOutputRegressor(m_ske,n_jobs = 4) #this just improves speed, right?
    foo =cross_val_score(m_multi, X_train, y_train, cv=10) #so we create lots of forests with i trees
```

and then we track foo with an array, basically adding [i,foo.mean() and foo.std()] to a running list.  At which point I will take the i corresponding to the mean nearest 1, and look at mean-square-error or mean-absolute-percentage-error (which is what my engineers like to see minimized)

By the size of my dataset, I know this is going to tax my computer, and take a day (or more) to complete.  Is this a sound strategy?  Should I try something else?

Comment: From a statistical point of view, there's no reason to not just train a single random forest with the maximum number of estimators your patience will bear.  Random forest is *not* sensitive to overfitting when many estimators are used, as they simply lower the *variance* of the model.  Of course, you may want to use as little estimators as possible for implementation reasons, in which case you should fit the full model and then simply truncate it to a smaller number of trees.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about efficiency, you should probably increment `i` in that code, it's going to run forever as is.  Better to use a `for` loop to avoid that kind of thing.